# Reading Data From MongoDB to Arduino Serial monitor

Tags: node.js

I tried reading data from MongoDB (using nodejs as my server) to arduino serial monitor using the sim9000A to get this reading to the arduino board. After confirming all physical and network connection, the response displayed is "+HTTPACTION:0,301,0". The response meant that the server is redirecting the request to a permanent domain. I used rail.app to host my server. Anytime I try the end-point in postman ,it is working. Anytime I try the URL on browser, it is working. But fails to display the data on serial monitor

Answer (score 0):

That stinks to me like a common server setups nowadays, a permanent (301) redirect to ‘https’ (no touching over dirty old http)
You probably don’t notice it in the browser as it will follow the 301 directive automatically. Can you check the full response headers that your Arduino doodah is receiving?

If it is a redirect to a secure connection there are few ways around it, see if you can dig a bit more info on that response that you are getting and post it here.

Comment: Thanks. The error shows that it is redirecting the server to a permanent page